# Python - how to split a string list into two?

Tags: python

There is a list like:

```
list = ['AB', 'CD', 'EF', 'GH']
```

I would like to split this list like:

```
first =  ['A', 'C', 'E', 'G']
second = ['B', 'D', 'F', 'H']
```

Now I did like this :

```
for element in list:
    first.append(element[0])
    second.append(element[1])
```

Is it a good way? Actually, the length of list over 600,000.

Comment: Seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: You can just do `first, second = zip(*l)` (granted zip will return tuples, which you could then cast into a list.

Comment: Very similar: [Python: split a list based on a condition?](//stackoverflow.com/q/949098), except instead of a condition you are splitting each value.

Comment: @Bahrom: that works in Python 3 too.

Comment: Ah, good point @MartijnPieters

Comment: Your way seems perfectly fine, to be honest. If you know for sure you always have two characters, you can do `for c1, c2 in my_list:`

Comment: @Bahrom the thing I don't like about that approach is that the `*` splat operator actually materializes a `tuple`, so, if the number of arguments is large, this becomes increasingly inefficient.

Comment: @Bahrom although, on my own initial tests it seems to beat out the naive approach by a good bit, I guess there's a major advantage to pushing the iteration out of the interpreter level...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
list = ['AB', 'CD', 'EF', 'GH']

first, second = zip(*list)
print(first)
print(second)
```

Output:

```
('A', 'C', 'E', 'G')
('B', 'D', 'F', 'H')
```

Answer (score 1):

Looping through the list and appending to a pair of empty list can be done something like the below shown example.

```
 list = ['AB', 'CD', 'EF', 'GH']
 first=[]
 second=[]
 for f in list:
    first.append(f[0])
    second.append(f[1])
 print(first)
 print(second)
```

> The output would be like
>
> ['A', 'C', 'E', 'G']
>
> ['B', 'D', 'F', 'H']

Comment: How is your code different from what OP posted in the question?